# Cross platform framework for mobile dev (with notification and background service)

Tags: cross-platform, framework, mobile, notification

I am looking for a **cross platform framework** that support Android and iOS.

But the problem is: the framework should be able to

- Run *background services* at the boot of the phone;
- Push *notifications*.

We are two students, we don't have much money, so the framework should be free.

I already looked into *Ionic*, but it seems that it doesn't support background services.
I also took a look at *Xamarin* but it seems that we have to do two different code for iOS and Android if we want to use a background service.

Is it something that exist ?

Comment: I have the same question, have you took a look at react-native?